# Group_by inside case_when in R

Tags: r, group-by, nested, dplyr, case-when

I am trying to run the following: for every `id`, create a new variable (`v2`), which is

- `"F"` when `grp=1` (`grp` is the run-length type `id` based on the variable `phase`),
- `"S"` when `grp<=2` & within the running `id` (`grp`) the variable `q` changes,
- `"T"` when `grp>2` & within the running `id` (`grp`) the variable `q` changes.

My main issue here is how can I include a `group_by()` function or equivalent within `case_when()` ? I tried the following:

```
df<-df %>% 
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(grp = rleid(phase), v2 = case_when(phase == 'First' ~ 'F',
                                                      phase == 'Second' & grp <= 2 & group_by(phase)%>% any(q != lag(q))%>% ungroup() ~ 'S', phase == 'Lane change' &
                                                        grp > 2 & group_by(phase)%>% any(q != lag(q)) %>% ungroup()  ~ 'T'))
```

But I get an error :

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for
> 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Any ideas?

Dummy data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
phase <- c("First", "Second","Second", "First" , "Second","Second","Second")
q <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2)

df<-data.frame(id,phase,q)
```

Desired output:

```
v2<- c("F", NA, NA, "F", NA, NA, "S")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: your sample `v2` is length 8, but there are only 7 `ids` -- is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that, I edited my question now :)